# How can I add automatically CRUD permissions to a django model inside the Meta class?

Tags: django, django-models, permissions, authorization, django-guardian

Imagine I had the following model

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    body = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        permissions = permission_generator()
```

and what I want is that the `permission_generator()` to generate the tuple

```
(
    ('create_pet', 'create post'),
    ('read_pet', 'read post'),
    ('update_pet', 'update post'),
    ('delete_post', 'delete post'),
)
```

In a way that I could reuse in all my models without repeating myself each time I define a new model.

how can something like this be implemented?

Comment: You can define abstract model with CRUD permissions at Meta.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out that django adds by default

- add_modelname
- change_modelname
- delete_modelname

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can create abstract model and inherit it. For example:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
        permissions = (
            ('create', 'Create'),
            ('read', 'Read'),
            ('update', 'Update'),
            ('delete', 'Delete')
        )

class Cat(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField()
```

When you inherit that model and do data migration these permissions will be added to `django_permissions` table and will look like:

`app | cat | Permission name`